# Lines for a gpkg not being added to a map in leaflet in R, but lines plot fine in ggplot

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm trying to plot lines from a gpkg using leaflet, but many of the lines are missing. I don't think it is a problem with the gpkg of sf, because all the lines plot fine when using ggplot. Here is some example code:
`leaflet() %>% addPolylines(data=subset(waterWaysDb_sf)`

vs

`ggplot(data = waterWaysDb_sf) + geom_sf()`

And here is the gpkg: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13SPdY25C0JMJEqSqG4uEGIvUl4NqDsYG/view?usp=sharing

I saw some folks in other questions mention updating leaflet and ensuring that names(st_geometry(thegpkg)) = NULL, but neither of those have helped here.

Here are the outputs using leaflet: [image]

And here are the outputs using ggplot: [image]

You can see that most of the interior waterways in the US are missing from the leaflet plot.